# Terminology for a change in a state's status without a change in its constitution

Tags: constitutional-law, legal-terms

This will be a terminology question, but first I have to explain some situations.

In the U.S., each state has a written constitution that is higher than any act of the state legislature and is what grants the legislature its powers, and specifies how the state's government is organized. The constitution is drafted by statespersons within the state and voted on in a referendum within the state or within the area that is proposed to become a new state.

In all but one instance, when Congress as admitted a new state to the Union, a new constitution of that state took effect at the time of admission and superseded whatever system of governance existed there before that, and a new governor and other new officers of the state (legislators, judges, etc.) began their terms.

Before March 4, 1791, a polity then called the State of Vermont was neither one of the states of the Union nor a territory governed under and according to an act of Congress (as was done in many territories later), but was under a constitution drafted and put into effect within Vermont without any participation from outside Vermont, just as in states of the Union. In October 1790 Thomas Chittenden was sworn in to a one-year term as governor of the State of Vermont, succeeding Moses Robinson who had likewise been sworn in as governor of the State of Vermont one year earlier, and less than five months later when Vermont was admitted to the Union, he continued uninterrupted in the same one-year term as governor of the State of Vermont under the same constitution of the State of Vermont, as did all judges, sheriffs, members of the Governor's Council, etc.

So now my terminology question: Should one say that this was the only state that did not undergo an **internal constitutional discontinuity** at the time of its admission, or would some other phrasing be more correct or otherwise better?

Comment: What’s the legal question as opposed to the English language question?

Comment: Or the [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) one?

Comment: I repent! I have rethought my answer on terminology, and will rewrite it when I get a chance. The short version is that natural science and constitutional law share many terms, such as equilibrium (the word appears several times in the Federalist). I still think "a discontinuity" is too mathy, but that may just be me. In the meantime, you may find this interesting: https://www.jstor.org/stable/985175?seq=1

Comment: @Justaguy : There's also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutionary_breach_of_legal_continuity

Comment: @Justaguy BEGIN QUOTE Revolutionary breach of legal continuity is a concept in English constitutional law, which rationalises the historic English behaviour when one King (or regime) was deposed and a de facto ruler was recognised as the new de jure monarch (or republican authority). END QUOTE

Comment: @Justaguy : BEGIN QUOTE  More generally it is any process, unauthorised by an existing legal order, which results in the creation of a new legal order; whether or not the revolutionary change is brought about by violence. A technical breach of continuity might happen when the former constitutional arrangement is so inefficient that there is not even a practical legal way to amend it. END QUOTE

Comment: @Justaguy : BEGIN QUOTE the replacement of the Articles of Confederation with the United States Constitution was a technical breach of continuity, which did not result in a civil war only because of the very reason of the breach: the first USA defined by the Articles had a weak central government that therefore had no means to defend itself. END QUOTE

Comment: @Justaguy : The reason why the U.S. Constitution was a breach of continuity is that the Articles of Confederation required unanimous ratification, at that time meaning all 13 states, whereas the Constitution went into effect upon ratifications of only nine state, the other four in effect being illegally expelled from the Union and invited to re-join. And a device that made it it successful was the Constitutional requirement that all who hold public office, not only at the federal level but within each state, but swear allegiance to the Constitution, so none can...

Comment: @Justaguy : ... so none can conscientiously object to the illegality under the Articles of Confederation, of the Constitution's mode of initial establishment.

Comment: I might add that another reason why the illegality of what happened in 1787 and 1788 did not result in attempts at enforcement is that hardly anybody cared. Members of the Congress of the Confederation acquiesced cheerfully in the illegal means by which their offices were abolished.

Comment: @Justaguy : The point of your last comment escapes me. I wasn't saying that what happened in 1787 and '88 was not revolutionary; I was just commenting on the reasons why no violence was involved.

Comment: I obviously misunderstood what you meant, so I deleted my earlier comment. It might help to know more context for your question. Are you working out for yourself how to think about this issue, or are you planning to use this phrase somewhere, say in a paper or speech? And what exactly do you mean when you way this was an "*internal* constitutional discontinuity"? Do you mean that that the constitution is internal, or that the reason for the discontinuity is internal?

Comment: @Justaguy : By "constitutional discontinuity" I just mean that a new constitution replaces whichever regime formerly was the supreme law. By "internal" I meant that it's within the state, as opposed to a change in the state's status within the larger community. Thus Vermont's admission to the Union altered its status from that of an independent sovereign country to one of the states subject to the Constitution of the United States and entitled to representation in the Congress and in the electoral college, etc., but unlike what happened with other states admitted to the Unions by.....

Comment: ....act of Congress, there was no immediate change in the state's constitution nor did a new governor or other offices begin their terms of service at that time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic.

Comment: The phrase "internal constitutional discontinuity" is dreadful and one could do better, but I don't think it is a legal issue. It might be an issue of political terminology but not legal terminology.

Comment: I think tht terminology of how to describe the legal status of a nation or a sub-national entity such as a US state or territory is still sufficiently "legal terminology" to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

**Law and language: You are asking the wrong question**

I take your point, but I'd say you are asking the wrong question. The more interesting question is why Vermont did not need to change its constitution upon statehood. The answer is simple: Vermont had this constitution because, **from its beginning,** Vermont's citizens **hoped for statehood.** They made this clear in their very first constitution, written in 1777. After explaining at length why Vermont could not remain in either the British Empire or New York state, the [preamble](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/vt01.asp) says Vermont should be:

> a *free and independent State*; and a...proper form of government, should exist in it, *derived from*, and *founded on*, the *authority of the people* only, **agreeable to the direction of the honorable American Congress.**

Except for Vermont, Texas, California and West Virginia, the rest of the new states needed new constitutions because they had been territories of the US before statehood. As such, they did not have constitutions.

Only Vermont and Texas were "independent" until statehood. Unlike Vermont, Texas **had** to change its constitution before statehood because its constitution explicitly provided for national powers. For example, [Sections](https://tarltonapps.law.utexas.edu/constitutions/texas1836/a2) 4 and 5 of Article II of the Constitution of the Republic of Texas gave its Congress the power to:

- To declare war, grant letters of marque and reprisal, and to regulate captures.
- To provide and maintain an army and navy, and to make all laws and regulations necessary for their Government.

Obviously, these powers are inconsistent with statehood.

**How to talk about drastic change in governance institutions**

I see what you mean about there being a discontinuity, but I'd be wary of mathy metaphors, such as discontinuities, bifurcations, catastrophes or singularities. I'd stick with words commonly used to describe drastic constitutional change. For example, "Vermont was the only new state that did not have a *constitutional revolution* when it became a state."

Having said that, I realize that constitutional historians and others love to talk about continuities, so why not use discontinuity?  My only caveat is that usually, they are talking more broadly than your wording ("a discontinuity") suggests.

Comment: California had a constitution which was ratified in Nov. 1849, and was admitted to the union 1 year later; it was amended 3 times during statehood, and revamped in 1879. The rationale for CA is probably the same.

Comment: @user6726 : Did California's constitution change upon its admission to the Union? Was a new governor sworn in simultaneously with its admission to the Union?

Comment: "Revolution" seems like the wrong word because a revolutionary system is one that is not condoned by the old system that it displaces. Whereas when, for example, the easternmost part of the Northwest Territory became the State of Ohio, the establishment of the new constitution of Ohio was contemplated in advance and condoned by the legal system already established.

Comment: "remain in New York State" seems a bit misleading. My impression is that after the king awarded the disputed territory to New York rather than to New Hampshire (which had governed there for 15 years) the government of New York never succeeded in governing there because of widespread resistance to a regime that refused to recognize claims to land based on the laws of colonial New Hampshire.

Comment: @MichaelHardy California's constitution did not change; it was adopted in anticipation of statehood.

Comment: Did the state acquire a new governor and other new officers simultaneously with admission to the Union? Or did the same ones continue terms of office that were already underway?

Comment: @user6726 I had hoped to avoid talking about CA, but you are right, so I'll go edit to add in CA.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The situation in CA was a mess. The short answer is that Congress could not agree on what to do about CA b/c of its impact on slavery. As a result, CA never became a territory. It had no civilian government, and was governed by a military governor. The last military governor, Bennett Riley, called the CA constitutional convention on his own authority. He served until statehood.

Comment: @Justaguy : If he served until then, would that mean a new governor was sworn in then?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: It's easy to look up.  Apparently a civilian government was formed, and a civilian governor (Peter Burnett) sworn in, on December 20, 1849, several months *prior* to California's admission on September 9, 1850.  Burnett remained in office through admission and served until January 9, 1851, when he resigned and was replaced by his Lieutenant Governor, John McDougal.

Comment: @Justaguy: But not simultaneously with admission; see my comment above.

Comment: @NateEldredge Exactly! This is why I ignored CA in my original answer.

Comment: There isn't really any way a new governor could have been sworn in *on* September 9, 1850, because the news of admission didn't reach California until October 18, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Hardeman_Burnett#The_Burnett_Administration).

Comment: @MichaelHardy In his original dictionary, published in 1828 Webster defined a revolution in politics as "a material or entire change in the constitution of government..." This is the only one of the seven definitions that is not about the natural world.  http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/revolution

Comment: You missed Kentucky and Maine. Kentucky was a part of Virginia until its admission as a new state in 1792 (and the act of the legislature of Virginia consenting to its separation was actually passed three times---the first while the Articles of Confederation were still in effect) and Maine was a part of Massachusetts until its admission in 1820.

Comment: "they had been territories of the US" .... Actuallly, lots of them were _parts_ of organized territories rather than being the whole territory.

Comment: It seems to me that the assertion that Texas _had_ to change its constitution is wrong, since certain provisions of its constitution would simply be rendered void by being subordinated to the Constitution of the United States, while others would remain in force. If, for example, the head of government of one of the states were called the president of that state rather than the governor, that would not be the first time, since that was done in New Hampshire, Delaware, and South Carolina. And I think Vermonts constitution, which continued in effect at the time of its admission.....

Comment: .....also had a few provisions inconsistent with its new status. I think that was part of the motive for its revisions two years after admission.